# Capatilize first letter of acronyms using the acronym package when using \underline

Tags: macros, acronyms

I am using the `acronym` package in LaTeX. For stylistic reasons and clarity, I want each corresponding letter in the full acronym description to be underlined (see MWE). This works fine except in one use case, namely when I need to capitalize the acronym at the beginning of a sentence using `\Ac{}`. It seems that, due to the `\underline{}` command the first letter of the acronym is not being recognized and thus, not being capitalized. For clarity, I am looking for a solution that uses the `acronym` package (not the `glossaries` package for instance) as I am obligated to use a template that is provided by my university. Does anybody have any solution? Any help would be appreciated. Cheers!

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{acronym}

\begin{document}

\Ac{DoS} attacks should be capitalized but it is not. \Ac{w.r.t.} without the underline works fine.

\begin{acronym}
    \acro{DoS}{\underline{d}enial-\underline{o}f-\underline{s}ervice}%
    \acro{w.r.t.}{with respect to}%
\end{acronym}

\end{document}
```

[image: mwe_output]

My first idea was that, in the same line that the `acronym` package lets you declare a custom plural version of an acronym I could define a custom capitalized version of each acronym, but I didn't find any standard way to do this. Redefining the `\Ac{}` command such that it can "look through" any styling would also be an option I think, but I have to little knowledge of LateX to accomplish such a feat.

Comment: Will the first character of *all* acronyms be underlined?

Comment: I wouldn't say that's true by definition, but yes, for all 80+ acronyms I use the first letter is part of the abbreviation. But that does indeed raise an interesting alternative, maybe it would be easier to define a macro that underlines the first letter of each acronym. Then again, I would not have the skills to do that :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Update

The original answer works with TeX Live 2022 but as mentioned by Bart Wolleswinkel and Dai Bowen in the comments: it does not work with TeX Live 2023. The reason is that the definition of `\MakeUppercase` has changed. This command is used in the definition of the command `\@firstupper` which is defined by the package `acronym`.

A solution is to redefine the command `\@firstupper` to use `\text_titlecase_first:n`.

Moreover in the answer below, a command `\acrounderline` is defined. This will underline the first letter and the first letter after each `-` in the second argument before passing this to `\acro`.

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=6pt,varwidth]{standalone}
\usepackage{acronym}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\makeatletter
\renewcommand { \@firstupper } [1] { \text_titlecase_first:n {#1} }
\makeatother
\tl_new:N \l__BartWolleswinkel_acro_underline_tl
\newcommand { \acrounderline } [2]
  {
    \tl_set:Nn \l__BartWolleswinkel_acro_underline_tl {#2}
    \tl_replace_all:Nnn \l__BartWolleswinkel_acro_underline_tl { - } { - \underline }
    \tl_put_left:Nn \l__BartWolleswinkel_acro_underline_tl { \underline }
    \acro {#1} { \l__BartWolleswinkel_acro_underline_tl }
  }
\ExplSyntaxOff
\begin{document}

\Ac{DoS} is capitalized without braces around \verb|\underline{d}|.

\Ac{w.r.t.} works.

\Ac{DoS2} works as well and also works with for example \verb|\textbf| if there is a pair of braces around it.

\begin{acronym}
    \acro{DoS}{\underline{d}enial-\underline{o}f-\underline{s}ervice}%
    \acro{w.r.t.}{with respect to}%
    \acrounderline{DoS2}{denial-of-service-{\textbf{2}}}%
\end{acronym}

\end{document}
```

## Original answer

A solution is to use an extra pair of braces: `{\underline{d}}`.

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=6pt,varwidth]{standalone}
\usepackage{acronym}

\begin{document}

\Ac{DoS} attacks should be capitalized but it is not. \Ac{w.r.t.} without the underline works fine.

\begin{acronym}
    \acro{DoS}{{\underline{d}}enial-\underline{o}f-\underline{s}ervice}%
    \acro{w.r.t.}{with respect to}%
\end{acronym}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Hi @matexmatics, thanks for the answer; however, when I run your code snippet above, I don't get the same output, i.e. the D is still not capitalized. Any idea why that could be? I'm using Overleaf (if that should matter).

Comment: @BartWolleswinkel Is the D capitalized if only the code from the above answer is used? Or is the D not capitalized in a larger document? It might be that in a larger document, interfering packages are loaded.

Comment: @matexmatics compiling your exact answer I get a lower case d from the `\Ac{DoS}` on Overleaf's 2023 TeX Live

Comment: If I use your exact code snippet in Overleaf, the D is not capitalized and I get a lowercase d, same as @Dai Bowen.

Comment: @BartWolleswinkel See updated answer.

Comment: @DaiBowen See updated answer.

Comment: Thanks, you're an absolute legend! Works like a charm, and without any additional package :)